# App Shows Old XIB Instead of Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib, uistoryboard

I'm updating an old iOS project that uses XIB files but want to convert to Storyboard. I created my Storyboard, connected it with the appropriate ViewControllers, removed any references that I can find to the XIB files, and set the Main Interface of the project to use my Storyboard.

However, when I run my app it still shows the XIB files instead of using the Storyboard; as if there's something still referencing them. The only one that shows the Storyboard is the initial scene/ViewController (and it's most likely because it's a newly created ViewController).

I've looked at other solutions online but to no avail. I tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Deleting DerivedData folder
- Restarting Xcode and my computer
- Updated MyApplication-info.plist
- Removed references to ViewControllers from XIB files
- Tried removing XIB files from project (it'll show a black screen because file is missing)

The original project target iOS 5.1, the new 6.0, and I'm using Xcode 5. Is there anything that I might be missing?

**Edit:** I'm not programmatically segueing to the other controllers; I have the Storyboard take care of that. The only thing I do in the first ViewController is send a string text to the next one:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NextViewController *   nextController;

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SegueToNext"])
    {
        nextController = [segue destinationViewController];
        [nextController initWithTitle:@"New"];
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This is the code for the ViewController that is showing the XIB file instead of the Storyboard. As you can see, there are no calls related to loading/pushing new controllers or anything that should relate to the XIB.

```
#import "NextViewController.h"

@interface NextViewController ()

@end

@implementation NextViewController


-(id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) title
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = title;

        // Load the dictionary
        self.dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NewDictionary"
            ofType:@"plist"]];
    }

    return self;
}


-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Render new slide
    [self renderOpening];
}


-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}


-(void) renderOpening
{
    // 1st slide
    NSLog(@"renderOpening");

    // Initial settings for opening slide; all are UIOutlets (UIButton, UIImageView)
    back.hidden = YES;
    diagram.hidden = YES;
    next.hidden = NO;
    text.hidden = NO;
    avatar.hidden = NO;

    avatar.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar"]
        rescaleImageToSize:CGSizeMake(150, 150)];

    text.text = @"Hello World";
}

@end
```

Comment: include your `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` implementation and an example of how you present/push a `viewController`. you should ideally be using a `segue` to transition to other `viewController`s.

Comment: My -didFinishLauchingWithOptions: function is empty; I made sure to remove the reference to the XIB. Also I do use segues to transition (how could you not when using Storyboard? :D ).

Comment: just checking. it seems fine but I'd suggest you post your segue related code for one of your problematic `viewController`s

Comment: The only segue code I have is **prepareForSegue**, which just calls the function of the next ViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ViewController that I was segueing to, I called a custom function which returned a reference to a newly created object of the ViewController class itself:

```
-(id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) title
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.title = title;

        // Load the dictionary
        self.dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NewDictionary"
            ofType:@"plist"]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

It was left there from the old code, and I completely overlooked it. It was no longer needed now that I was using Storyboard. So instead of seeing the ViewController that I was segueing into, it was showing the old XIB file. Deleting the XIB file from the project showed an empty, black view, and removing the code **[super init]** showed the correct Storyboard ViewController.

Although I got it working, I'm still not certain as to why it was showing the old XIB file, even though I removed references to it.

Answer (score 0):

Within your appDelegate class file, remove any code that directs the app to launch to your old initial xib. (From within the didFinishLaunching' method) You don't need to replace it with any code to start the storyboard as this selects this from the 'Development Info' section - see below.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Then click on your project and under the tab of 'General' within the 'Development Info' section, make sure your storyboard is selected as the main interface - see picture below.

[image]

Also, if you select the view controller from the storyboard that you want the app to initially start with and select it. Then go to the RHS utilities area and make sure the 'Initial Scene [ ] Is Initial View Controller bock is selected, please see picture.

[image]

I hope this helps,

Cheers

Jim

Comment: Yep, I've got all those already covered. The initial ViewController is the only one that shows correctly, from the Storyboard. All others, which use segues, somehow transition back to using XIB.

Comment: Hi Robert, I take it your segues are programatic, in which case could you show some of your segue code?

Comment: Hey Jeely, I'm not programmatically segueing to the next controller; I have Storyboard take care of that. I posted the only thing I do with segues, which is pass a string to the next ViewController.